# Reactjs Dropdown Menu not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm creating with reactjs Navbar which should include an dropdown menu component. I took the example from react bootstrap.

```
 import React from 'react';
import {NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function Dropdown() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="dropdown-style">
     <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

But when I run this code the dropdown menu does not open in the front. 
But the dev-mode shows me that it's actually opening.

The dropdown menu is only showing when I'm including this css-style

```
.dropdown-style{
  position: absolute;
```

But when I shrink the window then this component tears up the whole navbar when I merge it to the burger menu

I tried

```
{ .z-index: 999 }
```

But this didn't work.

Here is the navigation component

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };
  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="nac-center">
          <div className="nav-header">
            <Link to="/">
              <img src={logo} alt="foo" id="foo" />
            </Link>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="nav-btn"
              onClick={this.handleToggle}
            >
              <FaAlignRight className="nav-icon" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="ul-width nav-font">
            <ul
              className={this.state.isOpen ? "nav-links show-nav" : "nav-links nav-terms"}
            >
              <li className="navbar-top">
                <Link to="/support"
                  onClick={(this.state.isOpen) ? this.handleToggle : null}>
                  Support
                    </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="navbar-top">
                <Link to="/aboutus"
                  onClick={(this.state.isOpen) ? this.handleToggle : null}>
                  <nobr>About Us</nobr>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="navbar-top">
                <Link to="/foo"
                  onClick={(this.state.isOpen) ? this.handleToggle : null}>
                  foo
                  </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="navbar-top">
                <Dropdown/>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/
go through this link ,you will get the solution,may be some js or css file you have not imported

Comment: i had bootstrap already installed and just did it step by step again, but that didn't help unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

I've found out for myself now. 
If one of you have the same problem, just overwrite the css-class with `.dropdown-menu { position:relative !important }`

it seems that `dropdown-menu`  is written by react itself and you just have to overwrite it.